# how can i generate one letter with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var alhpabet = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * alhpabet.lengthS));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

How can I generate one letter with javascript?

Comment: Do you also need the letter to be inserted to the `demo` element?

Comment: `alhpabet.lengthS` > `alhpabet.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.

Your Math.floor function gets a random *index*, but not the letter. Also, your 'array' wasn't actually an array, you need each letter in quotes, separated by a comma. Alternatively, you can call `split` on a string but lets ignore that for now.

Once you have the index, you can return the letter found at that index by putting `alphabet[index]`.

Also, I'm sure you saw the comments but `lengthS` should be `length`. And technically `alhpabet` should be `alphabet`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
  var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * alphabet.length));
x.innerHTML = alphabet[index];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
 function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var min = "A".charCodeAt(0);
  var max = "Z".charCodeAt(0);
  var c = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
     x.innerHTML = c;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ASCII](http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii2.htm?PHPSESSID=7f26d9c37b999bab811b886edc99bde3). The range for uppercase alphabet letters is from 65-90.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var charCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
    x.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. As you have created `alphabet` variable as an array, you should use the only first `alphabet[0]`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo"),
      alphabet = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"],
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet[0].length);
  x.innerHTML = alphabet[0][random];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a string and not an array with a string inside. Then take `length` propery for multiplying the random number.

For the result take the random value as index for the string to get a single letter.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo"),
        abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    x.innerHTML = abc[Math.floor((Math.random() * abc.length))];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You are printing out a number but not a letter as asked in the OP